# What can I do with an Exited but Not -- Stopped? Removed? -- Container?

Tags: docker, containers

Using docker, I can run a `bash` shell using the following command

```
% docker run -it ubuntu bash
root@be22427630bf:/#
```

When I exit this container, it no long shows in my list of running processes

```
% docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

However, it will show up as an exited container

```
% docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
31cdad549e46   ubuntu    "bash"    6 minutes ago    Exited (0) 6 minutes ago              thirsty_poincare
```

I can remove my container from this list via the `rm` command

```
% docker rm 31cdad549e46
31cdad549e46
% docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
```

I can avoid this by starting my container with the `-rm` option.

```
% docker run -it --rm ubuntu bash
root@be22427630bf:/# exit
exit

% docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
```

So that's my immediate problem solved but it leaves me with a question. What, if anything, can I do with an exited container?  Or, put another way, why does Docker keep an exited container around.  Put a third way my understanding of containers is they're just linux processes and my understanding of linux processes is once they're stopped they're gone.  However, Docker containers don't disappear after they've been exited so I'm unsure what it even means to have an exited by not removed container?

**Update**: Editing because it was suggested that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75129675/use-case-for-excluding-rm-flag-when-running-a-container) had an answer for my question which -- isn't quite true.  That question offers up one use case for an exited but not removed container (logs), but it didn't have another offered in the comments below (a exited but not removed container can be restarted) and it doesn't really get at the heart of this question, which is what does it even *mean* for a container to have exited but still be around.

Comment: While I know you can restart it `docker start thirsty_poincare`, I am interested in a bigger question. Why this state exists at all?

Comment: Oh, that's wild @kamilcuk -- I didn't realize you could restart a container like that, so that's one useful reason. I THINK the other reasons are so you can examine logs or other data that might have been produced in the file system.

Comment: Good question Paolo and good find -- it's definitely similar and related but it only mentions one use case (looking at stopped logs) -- whereas I'm interested more in the idea of "what does it even mean for an exited process (since containers are processes) to stay around and require deleting)".  Things like Kamil's comment above would be a legit answer to this question, which isn't an answer in the linked question.

Comment: A container isn't just a process, it is a whole environment in which a process can be run.

Comment: That's definitely a point of view @CherryDT -- but from another point of view a container, at it's most basic, is a namespaced/isolated linux process that has access to a specific set of files. Docker builds on the generic idea of a container to present that whole environment you mention.  Your comment _does_ zero in on the heart of my question though -- what sort of things can you do with an exited but not removed process that you can't with a docker container/process.

Comment: "what sort of things can you do with an exited but not removed process that you can't with a docker container/process?" You can look at the logs (and other files) in the filesystem layer of the container. I'm not aware of an easy way to do this by running a new container.

Comment: Maybe I misread your question. Are you referring to the difference between `exited` and `stopped`? Would be interested to know this too. I always thought stopped containers were explicitly stopped using the `docker stop` command, not sure though.

Comment: @MilanSimek Honestly I don't know what the common language is around all this -- stopped, exited, killed, etc.  Whatever state a container process goes into after its underlying linux process has exited but you can still see it in docker via `docker ps -a`